# No changes detected in mysql

Tags: mysql

I been using mysql 5.6 for a while now,
Sometimes when I make some changes in the procedure , table or function and try to save them MySQL refuses to save them and shows a error message like "No Changes detected". here I am not talking about changing cases or managing spacing. Even If I add some new column and add new condition in the procedure its unable to detect the change
Can anybody help me out with this MySQL bug
I have even upgraded to MySQL 5.7 but still problem persist.

Comment: "*No Changes detected*" is not a MySQL error message.  We can only help if you tell us the **exact** error message that MySQL displays.  It would also help to see the SQL that leads to that message, and probably your schema and sample data too.

Comment: Do you experience this issue using MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 8):

I overcome this bug by removing the "**DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`**" part from the editor and then click on "Apply". It works 99% of times.

Eg: For a function or procedure, below is the declaration you see at top. Just remove the DEFINER string as described above and try it.
**CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION/PROCEDURE**

Comment: Also noticed `DEFINER=root@localhost` comes automatically back to the function/procedure after altering.

Comment: Hi @toing_toing sorry, The enter button added the above empty comments. Coming to the point, After removing the DEFINER part, I haven't seen it getting added back in editor unless the procedure is closed and re-opened for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not a MySQL server error response, I assume you are trying to update your procedures with the MySQL visual tool workbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

I found bug reports on mysql.com pointing out similar issues. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68434

Those might be fixed with the latest version 6.0 of MySQL workbench.

If not, a possible workaround would be to drop and recreate procedures.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MySQL Work bench this means that the SQL script is identical to the copy in the database.

This generally happens for 1 of 2 reasons

Either the Files are Identical, or the script failed to parse as valid SQL and its has then defaulted to the original script. if you check the message log then the second one should say

> Action:Apply changes to [scriptName]_SYNTAX_ERROR
>   Message:No changes detected

this can be confusing as the Commit Dialogue only displays the message not the action

Comment: I have had it tell me hundreds of times that no changes are detected and then was able to successfully execute the same script manually.